# What was the origin of the night creatures in the Riddick universe

Tags: riddick-franchise, pitch-black

In the movie Pitch Black, the space vessel transporting Riddick and 40 other passengers crashes on a desolate planet after presumably being damaged by meteors. On that planet, there is permanent daylight that lasts 22 years due to the presence of 3 suns. At the end of the 22 years comes a prolonged night that is the result of an total eclipse caused by a neighbouring massive planet blocking out the suns and orbiting in synch with the desolate planet.

During this night, carnivorous flying creatures arise from their caves abd terrorise the night. They are credited with having wiped out other forms of life on the planet. The question is, if there once was life on that planet with creatures the size of the massive left over skeletons, then where were the flying carnivores then? Did they arrive aboard a space vessel such as the one that brought the geologists to the planet? Did they evolve right there and wipe out other life forms?

Comment: The "duplicate" is due to the unfortunate answer "we don't know", since as Thaddeus noted, no origin or backstory has been revealed regarding the [bioraptors](http://riddick.wikia.com/wiki/Bioraptor) or the [M6-117 planet](http://riddick.wikia.com/wiki/M6-117).

Comment: The page you've linked to states "The landing areas were also nuked but to no avail. Investigative autobots were also enlisted." about M6-117. Which movie shows this?

Comment: It wasn't in the final cut of the movie. It may have been in the special features/commentary or possibly The Chronicles of Riddick: Dark Fury. The wiki is unfortunately almost completely unsourced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the movie doesn't give a straight answer, there are three possible conclusions that the movie supports:

1) Predatory Evolution - It seems strange that there would be a species that went well over its 'circle of life' balance in which it consumed all available species within the known area of the movie. It did show the elephant grave yard of what appeared to be the indigenous lifeforms that were the alien elephants (called whales), and that none existed in the area anymore. Such mass consumption doesn't seem natural as evolution tends to bring things back into check in the predator/prey ratio. Since they were at the point of eating one another (and would have to do so in the 'sunlight' phase) you would think they would have exterminated itself unless the species has adopted both sides of the predator/prey ratio. I don't think a species can realistically survive being its own food source for a sustainable length of time, as it would eventually eat itself out of existance. There might be another food source that the movie doesn't cover.

2) Extraterrestials - They're from somewhere else, planted or crashed onto the desert planet. I wouldn't guess crash, with the large drawback of the bioraptors being so photosensitive that it would destroy them. It could be that they are a bioweapon planet on the planet, but their photosensitivty seems to make them a rather lopsided weapon, only useful on 'dark' planets or area without any strong light source.

3) Horribly Mutated - The species might have once been something else, but due to something like nuclear radiation or strange experimentation, have altered into the bioraptor. This is a little more plausible, as it is a native creature that didn't have a chance to strip the planet bare until the more recent past. The survivors of the movie assume that the bioraptors consumed everything on the planet, but there is nothing saying that industrial dump/nuclear testing/bioengineering didn't have a hand in it as well. Think Godzilla. Horrible, horrible Godzilla. The bioraptors could indeed be a bioweapon, but more of a testing phase, a species seeing if they can tailor a weapon to a specific condition. It could have been that they wanted something wiped out that was once subterrainian, but because of the dark phase of the planet, they come out every 22 years for *buffet a la terra*. Because of this, the bioraptors could indeed be the cause of the mass extinction event, or be a result of it from outside influences.

Comment: The mutation angle is quite possible. The bioraptors could have existed long before, but in balance with the other creatures. The mutation could have either resulted in their getting abnormally larger and therefore eating a lot more than before, or it could have caused them to reproduce faster and outstrip their food source.

Comment: A predator outstripping its prey is rare, but possible. Someone brought up that bioraptors were indeed weapons, admittedly biological, in which the creators tailored such a weakness so that they had no fear of leaving it behind and having it fall into enemy hands for further use against them. It's an interesting aspect of biological warfare.

Comment: The first theory is feasible if the creatures have far more offspring then they consume. Since we know nothing about their reproductive cycle, it's impossible to say.